What is the graph information ratio when one of the graph is complete
In the paper "Graph Information Ratio", the information ratio is defined to be $\textrm{Ir}(H/G)=\sup \{k/n:\exists \textrm{ a nonadjacency preserving mapping from } G^k \textrm{ to } H^n\}$, where $G,H$ are graphs, $G^{k}$ is the $k$-fold strong product of $G$, $\phi:G^k\to H^n$ is nonadjacency preserving if for any $g\not\sim g'$, $\phi(g)\not\sim \phi(g')$, $\not\sim$ means not adjacent and distinct.
I am trying to check that the information ratio is well defined. Let $A=\{k/n:\exists \textrm{ a nonadjacency preserving mapping from } G^k \textrm{ to } H^n\}$. Do we require that $A$ to be non-empty and bounded? If $G$ is complete, then $A$ is unbounded, will $\sup A=+\infty$? If $H$ is complete and $G$ is not complete, then $A$ is empty, then what will $\sup A$ be? $0$ or $-\infty$?

I don't see how either of these issues could lead to the information ratio not being well-defined. That's a question usually asked when there are multiple ways to represent the inputs, which could in theory lead to different answers, and that's just not the case here.

@MishaLavrov Sorry. I don't understand. Can you answer directly? What is $\textrm{Ir}(H/G)$ if $G$ is complete? Or do we not consider these two cases?

I mean, I think we don't usually consider these cases; I think you're right about what would happen if we did, and I agree that the definition is ambiguous when it comes to one of the graphs being complete. I just don't see a way that you could possibly resolve the ambiguity that would lead to the answer being "the information ratio is not well-defined in these cases".

@MishaLavrov Thank you. Then I will not worry about these two cases.

From the information theory point of view, they correspond to cases where either (1) We are communicating over a channel that turns all messages into the same undifferentiated noise, or (2) we don't have any distinguishable messages to send. It might be nice to define $\operatorname{Ir}(H,G)$ in such cases so that general results remain true when $G$ and/or $H$ is complete, but there's no interest in these case for their own sake.

@MishaLavrov Thank you for the explanation. So these cases are not useful in applications. I was thinking just in theory. Sorry my English is not very good. Thank you for your patiance.
